# WCF hosted on Windows Service throw FaultException

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wcf, service

Good morning,

I am trying to start a process through WCF hosted as Windows Service. The problem is that if I run process, it throw an exception. However for example message is normally shown. Where can be problem?

Scenaro 1:

1. I have WCF service with two methods:

   - One returns string "Hello World".
   - Second returns nothing but the code inside is: `Process.Start("C:\");`
2. I have Windows Service with Reference to this WCF project.

   - OnStart method creates host
   - This service is installed on the computer
3. I have Console application represents client

   - This project has Service reference to the Windows Service project (to host)
   - Now I create client instance and call function described above

Result: "Hello World" is shown on my console. But Process is not started - it throws FaultException.
[image]

Scenario 2:

Second thing what I tried is:

1. WCF service as above
2. Console application with reference to this WCF project. (host is created here)
3. Console application represents client.
   And calling methods from this client.

Result: "Hello world" is shown and process is started without any problem. 
[image]

I want to run first scenario. I think it can be something with the security problem.

thanks for help.

Edit: Added screenshots.

Comment: We need the exception details...

Comment: First screenshot shows exception details. Anyway it is FaultException http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(EHSFault);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%3Dv4.5);k(DevLang-csharp)&rd=true